# Plot a count of paired events with kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an event series describing connections and disconnections of nodes, like so:

```
{ type: "connectionStart", timestamp: 1478889508, node: 12 }
{ type: "connectionEnd", timestamp: 1478899508, node: 12 }
{ type: "connectionStart", timestamp: 1478889548, node: 13 }
{ type: "connectionStart", timestamp: 1478899612, node: 12 }
```

I'd like to create a visualisation showing me how many nodes are connected over time. "Connected" means that at a given time, there has been an event of type "connectionStart" for a node but not yet an event of type "connectionEnd".

Is this something that can be achieved with the data as-is with a query, and how would it look like? Or does it require the data to be pre-processed (i.e. pairs to be created)?

Answer (score 0):

The data has to be pre-processed. If you create an index of "nodes" that have "connected" properties Kibana can show you the total number.